# How to set SD card as default storage on Android Marshmallow?

Tags: applications, external-sd, storage, 6.0-marshmallow

I have a Lenovo K3 Note (K50a40) and I was running Android 5.0 Lollipop until last week. I had **set the default storage as SD Card** on lollipop in storage settings, but that option seems to have disappeared in Android 6.0 Marshmallow. It only allows users to "**Adopt the SD Card as internal storage**". I *do not want to reformat the SD Card* as internal, as that will result in encryption of the SD Card. **I just want the downloaded data, and the screenshots, Instagram pics, Whatsapp media etc to go to the SD Card**, as was the case in Lollipop with SD Card as the default storage.

Answer (score 1):

The applications need to support this in Marshmallow, and as of yet many applications do not support the changes that are needed in their code to allow this to occur in Marshmallow with the SD card setup as external storage.

The answer is that your app developers need to include this functionality in their apps, it is not a blanket Android setting. Unless the code is included in their apps, there is nothing you can do to change it in a stock device.

Comment: Is this specific to Marshmallow? Because all the data that I'm mentioning, (downloads, screenshots etc) was smoothly going to the SDCard on Lollipop.

Comment: Yes, it is specific to Marshmallow... 6.0 changed the way SD cards are handled.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue. Small phone storage and I'd like to move apps to SD card, but it doesn't look possible (as you say) in Marshmallow. Does that mean that I won't be able to install any more applications? Damn that sucks..

Comment: @Warrior To use your SD card as internal storage does require Marshmallow. Although, if you are rooted you could use an app like Link2SD or App2SD to move some of the apps to the SD card and regain some space.